# How do Addax defend itself from predators?

Tags: zoology, ecology, ethology, mammals, predation

The addax (*Addax nasomaculatus*) is a critically endangered antelope adapted to live in extreme desert conditions. It has long impressive horns that can potentially serve as a weapon because they are sharp. Does addax use its horn to fend off predators?

I read somewhere that addax is not a fast animal so trying to escape by running does not seem like a good option for defense.

[image: Picture of Addax and its horns, taken from Wikipedia, photographer: Zachi Evenor]

Picture of Addax and its horns, taken from Wikipedia, photographer: Zachi Evenor
https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Addax-Jerusalem-Biblical-Zoo-IZE-611.jpg